# Error in Facebook GraphAPI Version || GraphAPIError: Valid API versions are '2.8', '2.9', '2.10', '2.11', '2.12', '3.0', '3.1'

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have been creating an API for Facebook but there is a constant error stating "GraphAPIError: Valid API versions are '2.8', '2.9', '2.10', '2.11', '2.12', '3.0', '3.1'". Is there any solution around it as I have tried multiple solutions posted on internet/Stack overflow but there was no solution to get my situation resolved.

Please help me around this error :)

```
import pandas as pd
import facebook
import json


df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Ad_Account_ID','ad_account_name','study_id','study_name','cells_id','cells_name','cells_treatment_percentage','objective_id','objective_name','cell_id_updated',
                          'experiment_id','population_reached','impressions','frequency','spend','advancedScoreMean_test','advancedScoreMean_control',
                          'advancedScoreMean_incremental','advancedBreakthroughs_incremental','advancedCostPerIncrementalBreakthrough'])

z = 0
file_location = ('C:/xyz/Desktop/facbook-api/acesstoken.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(file_location)
Access_Token = df['Token'][0]
Brand_ID = '123xxxxxxx'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(Access_Token,version = 7.0)
k=0


profile = graph.get_object(Brand_ID + '?fields=adaccounts.limit(700){name,ad_studies{name,cells,objectives{name,results}}}')
print (profile)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoEG3.png)

Comment: If you look at the code from your screenshot, the library is validating the API version you specified, against an internal list of valid API versions - and that appears to be outdated. Go check if an updated version of the library is available; otherwise, you might need to find the place where `VALID_API_VERSIONS` is defined, and overwrite it there yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You may put the version number into quotes:

> graph = facebook.GraphAPI(Access_Token,version = "7.0")

From: https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html